# Is the number $0.1234567891011121314\ldots$ a rational or irrational number?

Tags: decimal-expansion, rationality-testing

> Is the number $0.1234567891011121314\ldots$ a rational or irrational number?

The number has a very clear pattern but however in order for the number to be a rational number it would have to be written as a/b.  The normal tricks of writing it as an equation and solving

$3.3333333... = x \\
10*3.333333 = 10x\\
33.333333 = 10x\\
30 + x = 10x\\
30=9x\\
x=30/9 \\= 10/3$

does not seem to work here

Comment: If it were rational, then it would eventually repeat.  Since it does not repeat, it is irrational.

Comment: It's not hard to show that if $x$ is rational, its pattern of decimal digits must eventually hit a **repeating** pattern. Your number has a clear pattern. Does it ever start repeating?

Comment: Some number theory books have dealt with this.  Just search on the web

Comment: Clearly, this has the sequence $12$ somewhere in its decimal expansion. It also has $112$ somewhere, and it has $1112$ somewhere, and it has $11112$ somewhere… Can you see why no rational number can have this property?

Comment: In fact, can you prove that, if $\mathbf a$ is _any_ sequence of digits (for example, $\mathbf a=13427$), then $\mathbb a$ appears somewhere in the decimal expansion of your number?

Comment: I voted to reopen this question by mistake. I will vote to close (as duplicate) if it gets reopened.

Answer (score 1):

The [Champernowne constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChampernowneConstant.html)
$$C = 0.12345678910111213141516\dots$$
is a transcendental real number, so it is also irrational.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) in base 10, which is in fact transcendental.

In order to be capable to write it as a fraction, you would need to have a repeating block of digits. Evidently, there does not exist such a repeating block, and thus it is irrational.